# How do I modify alloc'ed memory using its address in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

So I'm trying to modify data that I've allocated through `malloc()`/`calloc()` by using pointers...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ** sentence = calloc(4, sizeof(char *));
    sentence[0] = malloc(3);
    sentence[0] = "the";
    sentence[1] = malloc(5);
    sentence[1] = "quick";
    sentence[2] = malloc(5);
    sentence[2] = "brown";
    sentence[3] = malloc(3);
    sentence[3] = "fox";

    char *test = sentence[1] + 2;
    printf("*test = %c\n", *test);
    *test = 'a'; // This is where the error is occurring
    printf("*test = %c\n", *test);

    printf("sentence[1][2] = %c", sentence[1][2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind is telling me that I have "bad permissions for mapped region".
I've also tried replacing `sentence[1] + 2` with `&(sentence[1][2])`, which yields the same results. I know that I can always do `sentence[1][2] =`, but that's just in this dummy application. The target purpose is to be able to determine the address of a char (in alloc'ed memory, not [] array memory) at some point using indices, and then later on (once those indices have been lost), modify the char at that address. Is there any way to avoid this/achieve my target functionality?

Comment: the shortest way to make it work would be to remove everything and use `sentence[0] = strdup("the")` ... but you should study `memcpy`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc.

Comment: One thing you want to decide is: do you want a shallow copy that just makes aliases to the strings, or do you want a modifiable copy of the array? If the latter, do you really want a ragged array of pointers with no extra space and no locality of reference? If the answer is yes, you need to copy the source strings to the buffer you allocate.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1**

All the lines of the form

```
sentence[0] = "the";
```

are wrong.

1. The memory allocated by the previous line, the return value of `malloc`, is lost and is now a memory leak.
2. `senctence[0]` points to some read-only parts of your program. Any attempt to modify those value will result in undefined behavior.

**Problem 2**

```
char *test = sentence[1] + 2;
*test = 'a';
```

is not right. `sentence[1]` is a pointer to the read-only part of the program that holds `"quick"`. `test` points to the `"ick"` of that string. However, that is still in the read-only part of the program. Trying to change anything in that memory is cause for undefined behavior.

**Solution**

You can use `strdup` to get copies of the string that you can modify later.

```
sentence[0] = strdup("the");
```

Please note that `strdup` is not a standard library function. However, you can find example implementations in many places on the web.

**Deallocate Dynamically Allocated Memory**

As a matter of good coding practice, deallocate any dynamically allocated memory in your program.

Answer (score 3):

"quick" is constant string (=mapped region).

for example,

```
sentence[1] = malloc(5);    // if malloc returns 0x100, then 0x100 is assigned to sentence[1]
sentence[1] = "quick";      // assume that "quick"'s address is 0x200, 
                            // so you assigned 0x200 to sentence[1] again.
                            // this means 0x100 will be lost and it causes memory leak.
```

So to avoid leak,
You should call `strcpy()` instead of `= "quick";` then `1*test = 'a';` will have no error.

**You should alloc 1 more byte for `'\0'` so that you can make it null-terminated string.**

Comment: If you go with this method, you need to allocate six bytes for `"quick"`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `sentence[0] = malloc(3);` allocates three bytes of memory, and sets the pointer `sentence[0]` to point to that memory. The next line, `sentence[0] = "the";`, sets the pointer `sentence[0]` to instead point to a static duration (permanently existing), *constant*, array of four `char`s (including a `'\0'` at the end!). At this point, `sentence[0]` is completely unrelated to the three `malloc`ed bytes on the previous line; those bytes are leaked memory, and the pointer points to somewhere completely different.

Presumably what you wanted to do is copy the *contents* of `"the"` into newly-allocated memory. You can do that either by calling [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), which does both the allocation and copying, or with `malloc` and [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). If you go with the second method, remember that strings need one extra byte for the null termination.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gap in (your) understanding of how an assignment works.

```
sentence[0] = malloc(3);  // Allocates 3 bytes (subject to availability)
sentence[0] = "the";      // This makes sentence[0] point to a read-only, constant section in your memory map
sentence[1] = malloc(5);  // Allocates 5 bytes (subject to availability)
sentence[1] = "quick";    // This makes sentence[1] point to a read-only, constant section in your memory map
sentence[2] = malloc(5);  // Allocates 5 bytes (subject to availability) 
sentence[2] = "brown";    // This makes sentence[2] point to a read-only, constant section in your memory map
sentence[3] = malloc(3);  // Allocates 3 bytes (subject to availability) 
sentence[3] = "fox";      // This makes sentence[3] point to a read-only, constant section in your memory map
```

So, all of above memory that you have `malloc`ed, is leaked and lost.

Moreover, since all strings are read-only, any attempt to modify those will invoke Undefined Behaviour.

You can achieve what you are looking for this way:

```
if(sentence[0] != NULL)
{
    sentence[0] = strdup("the");
}
else
{
    // Handle the error here, that no memory was allocated
}
```

This will allow you to have a copy of "the" in an array that you can modify. Also note that to store `"the"` you need 4 bytes, not 3. The one extra byte is to have `'\0'`.

Finally, when you are done, before exiting de-allocate/free all the memory that you have allocated dynamically.